# The resampled image has many NaN values and does not cover the complete area of the input raster

Tags: resampling

when I resample an image of 20m to 240m resolution, the resampled image does not cover the whole area of the input image and does the resampling for some pixels in which I get many NaN values. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot highlighting the problems you are encountering?

Comment: What software are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There could be a couple of things going on here. First I would be sure to set my "Environments" to include a "Processing Extent" and I would set it to the input raster. Right-click the white background in the ArcToolbox or click the Environments button in the tool dialog. That should fix the extent problem. You could also set the SnapRaster to the input 20m Raster.

I would also be sure that if my raster stores numbers, that I do NOT use Nearest Neighbor but instead use Bilinear Interpolation or Cubic Convolution when converting or resampling the Raster.